# ideapad_laptop module makes iwlwifi stop working

Tags: drivers, 18.04

i was having some problems in using my ideapad 130s with ubuntu as the  wireless intel ac3165 did not work, but after a lot of unsuccessful workarounds it did work when i removed the ideapad_laptop module. i wanted to communicate this and see if someone has a explanation for the problem ( i do not even know if my system is 100% without this module,for example; when i close the lid of the laptop it does not even turn off the display...). i tried the live usb of ubuntu 18.04 and now i am using ubuntu budgie 18.04, both of then have this same issue.

Comment: The explanation will be long enough and of no practical value for a non-developer. Some kernel model specific quirk is needed for your laptop to get rfkill working properly. Laptop models appear faster than quirks are made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every laptop that I am aware of requires a small helper module to translate the special keys, Fn + F12, for example, into action. In your case, it is the module ideapad_laptop. My laptop uses thinkpad_acpi. Other examples include hp_wmi and dell_wireless.

In some cases, although the helper module loads, one or more of the intended actions does not occur. In your case, pressing the wireless key combination makes no change at all; the wireless remains blocked and won't scan and connect to any networks.

By trial and error, we have learned that, remarkably, *removing* the module then enables the wireless. As you have noted, the following enables wireless:

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop
```

If you wish to make it permanent, blacklist the module so that it never loads at all:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist ideapad_laptop  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

As to the explanation of the problem, it is simply a bug. I suggest that you search for and add to an existing bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu

As for the lid closing not turning off the display, I recommend that you review this: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-closelid.html Evidently, after you install *Tweaks*, you can customize the actions that take place upon closing the lid.

Comment: Thechnically it IS a bug, but it means that this laptop is not fully supported yet. I made these quirks for some time, now I dropped it.

Comment: ok so i will add a bug report , i really aprecciate the answers. its the first time i ask something online

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour